# ❗️[Error]: Webhook handler for Stripe event [evt_3NM8vqBAry7EbN3617epEYhQ] of type [payment_intent.succeeded] failed: User not found

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

I am using the "Run Payments With Stripe" firebase extension but I am getting an error in handleWebhookEvents function of it.

Here's the error info from firebase functions logs:

```
insertId: "64958d6c000d4b73500727b9"
labels: {2}
logName: "projects/esim-53007/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"
receiveTimestamp: "2023-06-23T12:17:49.103226088Z"
resource: {2}
severity: "ERROR"
textPayload: "❗️[Error]: Webhook handler for  Stripe event [evt_3NM8vqBAry7EbN3617epEYhQ] of type [payment_intent.succeeded] failed: User not found!"
timestamp: "2023-06-23T12:17:48.871283Z"
trace: "projects/esim-53007/traces/d89c9589ea88b3f90e202655d95198e8"
}
```

Here's the info about the request from the Webhooks logs in Stripe's dashboard:
payment_intent.succeeded (I manually removed the client secret here)

```
Response
200 OK
{
  "error": "Webhook handler failed. View function logs in Firebase."
}

Request
{
  "id": "evt_3NM8vqBAry7EbN3617epEYhQ",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2022-11-15",
  "created": 1687522664,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "pi_3NM8vqBAry7EbN361NT0KUe0",
      "object": "payment_intent",
      "amount": 1600,
      "amount_capturable": 0,
      "amount_details": {
        "tip": {
        }
      },
      "amount_received": 1600,
      "application": null,
      "application_fee_amount": null,
      "automatic_payment_methods": {
        "allow_redirects": "always",
        "enabled": true
      },
      "canceled_at": null,
      "cancellation_reason": null,
      "capture_method": "automatic",
      "client_secret": "",
      "confirmation_method": "automatic",
      "created": 1687522662,
      "currency": "usd",
      "customer": null,
      "description": null,
      "invoice": null,
      "last_payment_error": null,
      "latest_charge": "",
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
        "firebaseUID": "QHhVIUuwfoNBIKJwyZ60cCYIDon2"
      },
      "next_action": null,
      "on_behalf_of": null,
      "payment_method": "pm_1NM8vrBAry7EbN36lfBfXurI",
      "payment_method_options": {
        "card": {
          "installments": null,
          "mandate_options": null,
          "network": null,
          "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
        },
        "paypal": {
          "preferred_locale": null,
          "reference": null
        }
      },
      "payment_method_types": [
        "card",
        "paypal"
      ],
      "processing": null,
      "receipt_email": null,
      "review": null,
      "setup_future_usage": null,
      "shipping": null,
      "source": null,
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
      "status": "succeeded",
      "transfer_data": null,
      "transfer_group": null
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 2,
  "request": {
    "id": "req_1AVy85IsXf7ngi",
    "idempotency_key": "19f34329-4906-4876-a2df-789db27e950a"
  },
  "type": "payment_intent.succeeded"
}
```

I provided the firebaseUID in the metadata when I created the payment intent in my firebase function.

Any ideas why this happens?

Feel free to ask for more specific info if I left anything out.

I tried checking for the source code of the [handleWebhookEvents function in github](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/master/firestore-stripe-payments/functions/src/index.ts#L804) but for some reason the switch case that handles this specific event is empty from what I see(unless I missed something somehow)
[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: Yeah but I don't remember anything tbh, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a few things going on:

- Within the Stripe dashboard, there might be duplicate users. I recommend deleting all of them (if you're still testing, of course) and starting over with a fresh slate.
- You might have set everything up correctly with the Stripe -> Firebase communication (you're getting `200` statuses on your webhook logs), but you have to log in to your application with the account that you want to test with again!
- If you are trying to integrate everything with a web frontend, I had to redirect my user to a checkout session URL using the Stripe JavaScript library:

`<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>`

Then, I could do something like:

```js
  async function subscribe() {
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    const docRef = await db.collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).collection("checkout_sessions").add({
        price: '<a subscription identifier. it should look like "price_1NmhckH0SbC5Uq6HBAPQXXXX">',
        success_url: window.location.origin,
        cancel_url: window.location.origin
    })
    docRef.onSnapshot(async (snap) => {
        const { error, sessionId } = snap.data()
        console.log('error sessionId', error, sessionId)
        if (error) {
        alert(`An error occured: ${error.message} `)
        }
        if (sessionId) {
        console.log('sessionID', sessionId)
        const stripe = await loadStripe("<your public api key>")
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
        }
    })
  }

async function loadStripe(key){
    const stripe = new Stripe(key);
    return stripe
}
```

You can then go into the `Google Functions` UI and edit the functions to return more custom data if you'd like (ex. if a user has subscribed to a product, explicitly).

Answer (score -1):

The switch isn't empty, that syntax means all of those cases (event types, here) will be handled by the one block that follows the last `case` in the stack:

```
      case 'payment_intent.processing':
      case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
      case 'payment_intent.canceled':
      case 'payment_intent.payment_failed':
        // this handle all of the cases above
        const paymentIntent = event.data.object as Stripe.PaymentIntent;
        await insertPaymentRecord(paymentIntent);
        break;
      default:
```

You're getting this error because the customer is not found in your customer collection, so you'll need to investigate why that is happening:

```
const customersSnap = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection(config.customersCollectionPath)
    .where('stripeId', '==', payment.customer)
    .get();
  if (customersSnap.size !== 1) {
    throw new Error('User not found!'); // this is the error you're seeing
  }
```

[Source code](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/master/firestore-stripe-payments/functions/src/index.ts#L644-L648)

Comment: Just kind of repeated the question.

Comment: I explained that the switch was not "missing" cases because of the way the stacked cases apply, and provided a pointer to the source code showing where this error originates to narrow the scope of the search for the issue.

Comment: Good call. My bad.